# How to rewrite this script from index.html into angularjs app.js

Tags: angularjs, refactoring

Currently I have this script in my index.html inside the head tabs. I should move this to app.js, right? Either way, can you help me? How do I modify the script to fit in app.js?
NOTE: I'm using angular.js so the app.js is an angular.module

```
    <script>
  function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 14,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.3332346,18.0280576)
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
              mapOptions);
  }

  function loadScript() {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&' +
              'callback=initialize';
      document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  window.onload = loadScript;
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the `loadScript` into an actual `<script>` tag within the `HEAD` of your document. It is unnecessary to load the script using JavaScript.

Once you've done that create a directive for your map:

```
app.directive('map', function mapDirective() {

    return {

        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            options: '=map'
        },
        link: function link(scope, element) {
            new google.maps.Map(element[0], scope.options);
        }

    }

});
```

Setup your HTML document to utilise the directive:

```
<section ng-controller="MapController">
    <div data-map="options"></div>
</section>
```

And then finally create your controller to pass in the map options:

```
app.controller('MapController', function MapController($scope) {

    $scope.options = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.3332346,18.0280576)
    }

});
```

Comment: Wow thanks! Great answer! But I haven't gotten it to work yet.
Furst I tried to implement all of it but then my app broke. So I started checking what's wrong and I don't know what exactly but as soon as I input the controller into controllers.js - the app breaks. 
It doesn't render.
Even if I leave it empty like this: 
.controller('MapController', function MapController($scope) {



});
What's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I've modified the answer to include the new HTML. It's because we have an isolate scope and a controller on the same element, and each one is attempting to create a new scope.

Comment: Thanks but that's not it. I think the problem lies in the Ionic Framework starter app "Tabs". It comes with some sort of sate feature "Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states".
I don't fully understand it and every time I try to add a control, directive whatever - the app breaks...

So now I'm starting over with the ionic framework starter app "blank".
When I'm back on track I'll try your code again. Thanks :)